# Calculate percent increase/decrease from previous row value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
|date_start  | date_end    |amount | 
+------------+-------------+-------+
|2015-02-23  | 2015-03-01  |50     |
|2015-03-02  | 2015-03-08  |50     |
|2015-03-09  | 2015-03-15  |100    |
|2015-03-16  | 2015-03-22  |800    |
|2015-03-23  | 2015-03-29  |50     |
```

and I'd like to work out the percent increase/decrease for column `amount`, from the previous date. For example the result would be something like this,

```
|date_start  | date_end    |amount | perc_change | 
+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+
|2015-02-23  | 2015-03-01  |50     | 
|2015-03-02  | 2015-03-08  |50     | 0
|2015-03-09  | 2015-03-15  |100    | 50
|2015-03-16  | 2015-03-22  |800    | 700
|2015-03-23  | 2015-03-29  |50     | -750
```

I've searched and racked my brain for a couple of days now. Usually, I simply do this using server side code but now I need to contain it all within the query.

Comment: can you create [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), I did something similar in sql server I think I can adjust it to this...

Comment: Are you sure you are calculating percentage change? 50 to 100 is a 100% change, 100 to 800 is an 800% change...

Comment: here's the sql fiddle table, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c1ec6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT t.*,
 amount - (SELECT amount FROM transactions prev WHERE prev.date_end     < t.date_start ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT 1) AS changes
 FROM   transactions t
```

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that the previous row always ends exactly one day before the current begins (as in your sample data), then you can use a `join`.  The percentage increase would be:

```
select t.*,
       100 * (t.amount - tprev.amount) / tprev.amount
from atable t left join
     atable tprev
     on tprev.date_end = t.date_start - interval 1 day;
```

However, your results seem to just have the difference, which is easier to calculate:

```
select t.*,
       (t.amount - tprev.amount) as diff
from atable t left join
     atable tprev
     on tprev.date_end = t.date_start - interval 1 day;
```

Comment: Good catch noticing the dates were a single day apart! If that's consistent, it makes the query a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use window function it would be easier

select date_start,
       date_end,
       amount,
       LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date_start) as previous_amount,
       amount - LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date_start) as amount_diff,
       ((amount - LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date_start)) / (amount - LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date_start))) * 100 amount_diff_percentage
from your_table_name
```

Comment: ```
some time in divide you need to do cast 
so if you found that percentage value is not correct add cast to float,
  so percentage column will be edited to be like that   
 ((amount - LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date_start)) /cast (amount - LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date_start)) as float) * 100 amount_diff_percentage

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer might be more helpful to others if you explained how/why it works, and/or why this solution is better than the existing answers that have already been here for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks something like this, i dont have environment to test this select but i think it should work

```
    SELECT t1.date_start, t1.date_end, t1.amount, (t1.amount - t2.amount)  as  perc_change
    FROM table1 t1 
      JOIN table1 t2  ON t1.id = t2.id + 1 // here your join to 
   //get next row and calculate this perc_change field
```

Comment: got this error message... Column 'date_start' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

I started by joining each row in the table with the one that comes after it, like this:

```
SELECT m.date_start AS mStart, mt.date_start AS mtStart
FROM myTable m
JOIN myTable mT ON m.date_start < mt.date_start AND mt.date_start = (SELECT MIN(date_start) FROM myTable WHERE date_start > m.date_start);
```

This will join the tables so that each row can be seen with the following date if there is one. If there's not, the date is not returned.

Once you have those values, you can adjust the SELECT query to show you the percent change from the date before, like this:

```
SELECT 
  mT.date_start AS secondDate, 
  mT.amount - m.amount AS percentChange
FROM myTable m
JOIN myTable mT ON m.date_start < mT.date_start AND mt.date_start = (SELECT MIN(date_start) FROM myTable WHERE date_start > m.date_start);
```

I would like to make a note here that while you say 'percent difference' in your question, your expected results have nothing to do with percentage, but just difference in value. If you need to calculate this a different way, you can just adjust the select query above to meet your needs.

The last thing you will have to do is join this back to your original table to see all of the values together. This has to be done using a left join, in order for the first date of the table to be seen. Here is the final query:

```
SELECT m.date_start, m.date_end, m.amount, tmp.percentChange
FROM myTable m
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT 
    mT.date_start AS secondDate, 
    mT.amount - m.amount AS percentChange
  FROM myTable m
  JOIN myTable mT ON m.date_start < mT.date_start AND mt.date_start = (SELECT MIN(date_start) FROM myTable WHERE date_start > m.date_start)
) tmp ON tmp.secondDate = m.date_start;
```

And here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb734/5) example.

Comment: McAdam, works on SQL Fiddle but when executing via MySQL, why do i get an error message... Unknown column 'mt.date_start' in 'on clause'?

Comment: @user3768071 You've probably made a typo on one of the table aliases. Check closely.

Comment: that's what i first thought, so i'd copied your exact table and query without making any changes and i get the error

Comment: That's very strange. I'm willing to bet that somewhere one of us just made a typo. Are you sure you're using `tmp.secondDate = m.date_start` and not using `mt` there?

Comment: @user3768071 I thought MySQL was case-insensitive, but notice in my query I set the alias as `mT` but in one spot it's lower case `mt`? Try changing that and see if it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You case use the mysql var system :

```
SELECT date_start, date_end, IF(@last IS NOT NULL,ammount - @last , '' ) as perc_change, @last := amount as amount 
From table 
ORDER BY date_start;
```

the var @last is set at each passage, so column order between perc_change and amount is important

Comment: This is not guaranteed to yield correct results: the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)