# Finding changes in value by dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
datetime               |  value
-----------------------------------
2015-05-01 12:23:41    |  12 
2015-05-01 22:13:11    |  21 
2015-05-02 9:13:41     |  23 
2015-05-02 17:23:41    |  32
```

Each day has about 100 entries at random time. 
I need to calculate the following:

1. daily increase - difference between first entry of today and first
   entry of yesterday (for each day)
2. daily avg increase - difference between avg value today and avg
   value yesterday (for each day)

How can I write an SQL query to get these values?

Comment: What you tried so far? We are not here to do your job for you.

Comment: Are you still trying to figure this out?

Comment: yep, for first comment i want to say that i made calculations in ruby code, and they are ultra ugly, so i come here to get valid and beuty answer by solving it in pure sql., cause i tried and failed (i am rather bad at sql). Currently i am making my final university work, so i am a little busy, and when i get free i will refactor my ugly code, and accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do to get the first entry of each date is to group by the date portion, and get the minimum datetime like this:

```
SELECT DATE(dateCol), MIN(dateCol)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATE(dateCol);
```

This will help you see results like:

```
| 2015-05-01 | 2015-05-01 12:23:41 |
```

Once you have those values, you can join the two tables together to get each date next to the previous one, like this:

```
SELECT t1.firstDate, t2.secondDate
FROM(
  SELECT DATE(dateCol) AS wholeDate, MIN(dateCol) AS firstDate
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY DATE(dateCol)) t1
JOIN(
  SELECT DATE(dateCol) AS wholeDate, MIN(dateCol) AS secondDate
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY DATE(dateCol)) t2 ON t1.wholeDate < t2.wholeDate AND t2.wholeDate = (SELECT MIN(DATE(dateCol)) FROM myTable WHERE DATE(dateCol) > DATE(t1.wholeDate));
```

Then, all you have to do is adjust your select statement to get the difference. You also have to join back to the original table to get the values:

```
SELECT t1.firstDate, t2.secondDate, (s.value - f.value) AS difference
FROM(
  SELECT DATE(dateCol) AS wholeDate, MIN(dateCol) AS firstDate
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY DATE(dateCol)) t1
JOIN(
  SELECT DATE(dateCol) AS wholeDate, MIN(dateCol) AS secondDate
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY DATE(dateCol)) t2 ON t1.wholeDate < t2.wholeDate AND t2.wholeDate = (SELECT MIN(DATE(dateCol)) FROM myTable WHERE DATE(dateCol) > DATE(t1.wholeDate))
JOIN myTable f ON f.dateCol = t1.firstDate
JOIN myTable s ON s.dateCol = t2.secondDate;
```

For the second part, you'll need to calculate the average for each date, and then join the tables in a similar way to see the difference of the averages from date to date.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad147/8) example, and here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484373/calculate-percent-increase-decrease-from-previous-row-value) that might help you as well.

Answer (score -1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cc73/1

```
SELECT DATE(`datetime`), MAX(`value`)-MIN(`value`)
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE(`datetime`)

SELECT AVG(`increase`)
FROM (
SELECT DATE(`datetime`), MAX(`value`)-MIN(`value`) as increase
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE(`datetime`)
  ) as t
```