# SQL - Price increase over time

Tags: mysql

I am sure that this question has already been answered, I just don't know what I am looking for.

What I've got are price lists that update every month and I am looking for a query that lists all items (tnr) that increase in price by over 20%

In this case I'd like to the the "tnr"

```
136234194430
832124069830
183078059150
```

I could loop through all items that I know that there is a smarter, faster, more elegant way to do it

The dummy table to test stuff on

```
CREATE TABLE `pricelist` (
  `tnr` bigint(64) NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `discount` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `pricelist` (`tnr`, `price`, `discount`, `date`) VALUES
(183078059150, 33.89, 26, '2018-08-01'),
(514780535750, 78.73, 19, '2018-08-01'),
(121475122010, 521.54, 16, '2018-08-01'),
(726576581300, 168.36, 10, '2018-08-01'),
(832124069830, 22.69, 50, '2018-08-01'),
(342122275110, 131.5, 26, '2018-08-01'),
(345067567690, 6.34, 26, '2018-08-01'),
(121113618790, 195.5, 16, '2018-08-01'),
(511681969780, 291.74, 23, '2018-08-01'),
(411372385450, 129.75, 23, '2018-08-01'),
(15097806600, 46.68, 19, '2018-08-01'),
(613592995940, 259.47, 19, '2018-08-01'),
(135414163780, 17, 19, '2018-08-01'),
(726076671410, 68.91, 11, '2018-08-01'),
(136234194430, 36.86, 23, '2018-08-01'),
(541122685800, 10.25, 16, '2018-08-01'),
(514722202230, 83.19, 23, '2018-08-01'),
(125177976530, 257.12, 26, '2018-08-01'),
(114377922120, 19.18, 23, '2018-08-01'),
(642169317400, 2.54, 26, '2018-08-01'),
(14085256200, 16.44, 14, '2018-08-01'),
(114313045460, 22.46, 16, '2018-08-01'),
(331014284930, 1042.02, 19, '2018-08-01'),
(183078059150, 53.89, 26, '2018-09-01'),
(514780535750, 78.73, 19, '2018-09-01'),
(121475122010, 521.54, 16, '2018-09-01'),
(726576581300, 168.36, 10, '2018-09-01'),
(832124069830, 42.69, 50, '2018-09-01'),
(342122275110, 131.5, 26, '2018-09-01'),
(345067567690, 6.34, 26, '2018-09-01'),
(121113618790, 195.5, 16, '2018-09-01'),
(511681969780, 291.74, 23, '2018-09-01'),
(411372385450, 129.75, 23, '2018-09-01'),
(15097806600, 46.68, 19, '2018-09-01'),
(613592995940, 259.47, 19, '2018-09-01'),
(135414163780, 17, 19, '2018-09-01'),
(726076671410, 68.91, 11, '2018-09-01'),
(136234194430, 66.86, 23, '2018-09-01'),
(541122685800, 10.25, 16, '2018-09-01'),
(514722202230, 83.19, 23, '2018-09-01'),
(125177976530, 257.12, 26, '2018-09-01'),
(114377922120, 19.18, 23, '2018-09-01'),
(642169317400, 2.54, 26, '2018-09-01'),
(14085256200, 16.44, 14, '2018-09-01'),
(114313045460, 22.46, 16, '2018-09-01'),
(331014284930, 1042.02, 19, '2018-09-01');
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Mysql or SQL server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate percent increase/decrease from previous row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484373/calculate-percent-increase-decrease-from-previous-row-value)

Comment: The Idea was to use MySQL

Comment: I my eyes the answers given in [Calculate percent increase/decrease from previous row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484373/calculate-percent-increase-decrease-from-previous-row-value) wouldn't work because the lines are not in order

Comment: I'd like to the the "tnr" too

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - what do you mean by this stackoverflow.com/a/52393112/2469308 - when i click it - it took me in same page !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Determine a "forward price" for each tnr and date (new price on a next date), utilizing [Correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html).
- Using [Derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and grouping on `tnr`, filter (using Having clause) out the `tnr` having "growth" greater than 20%

Use the following query (**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28fac/1)**):

```
SELECT inner_nest.tnr, 100*(inner_nest.forward_price - inner_nest.price)/inner_nest.price as growth
FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.*, (SELECT t2.price 
                FROM pricelist AS t2 
                WHERE t2.tnr = t1.tnr 
                  AND t2.date > t1.date 
                ORDER BY t2.date ASC LIMIT 1) AS forward_price 
  FROM pricelist AS t1
) AS inner_nest 
GROUP BY inner_nest.tnr 
HAVING growth > 20
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick, never knew about derived tables!

Comment: @BenSchmidt Happy to help :)